# Searching webpage with regex

Tags: ruby, regex, web-scraping

I'd like to search through a webpage for sentences including `'small business'`, and do the same for every link on the page, three or four layers deep.

My attempt is this:

```
    def get_sentences
      sentences = []
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.brampton.ca/EN/Business/Pages/top-links.aspx"))
      @sentences = doc.search(/[^.]*small business[^.]*\./i)
      links = doc.search('a[href]').select{ |n| n['href'][/\.html$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] })

      doc1 = links.each { |x| Nokogiri::HTML(open(x)) }
      @sentences << doc1.search(/[^.]*small business[^.]*\./ig)
      links1 = links.each { |x| x.search('a[href]').select{ |n| n['href'][/\.html$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] }

      doc2 = links1.each { |x| Nokogiri::HTML(open(x)) }
      @sentences << doc2.search(/[^.]*small business[^.]*\./ig)
      links2 = links1.each { |x| x.search('a[href]').select{ |n| n['href'][/\.html$/] }.map{ |n| n['href'] }

      doc3 = links2.each { |x| Nokogiri::HTML(open(x)) }
        @sentences << doc3.search(/[^.]*small business[^.]*\./ig)
      end





edit, narrowed it down to this lol


@sentences = []
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_business"))
    regex = /[^.]*small business[^.]*\./i
    a = doc.traverse { |x| 
      if x.text =~ regex
        @sentences << x
      end
```

but i'm probably out of my league after a month.

..........worked!

Comment: did you figure this out? not sure what you're doing with `n['href'][/\.html$/]` - that's not a proper way to search regex that im aware of.

Comment: Hi, thanks.   I aborted, and resorted to just grabbing from a particular site, which worked.   Ill save taking down google for month 2.   ... I copied that regex from somewhere, think it works in the nokogiri syntax but not at 230am

Comment: "Ill save taking down google for month 2" gave me a good chuckle. i similarly abandoned an attempt a few weeks ago.